# Trying to use natbib, but I get an error that biblatex package is missing

Tags: biblatex, miktex, natbib, texmaker

I've installed TexMaker and MikTex on windows 10.
I've started with a template that used biblatex and am trying to change that to use natbib instead.

I've commented out all biblatex entries that I can find by searching for 'biblatex', and have the natbib packages added in my document.

I am getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing 'biblatex' package.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... {}
```

I've been into MikTeX and made sure that both biblatex and natbib are installed (plus I installed MikTeX to install packages on the fly).

I've tried the build command: `PdfLatex + View PDF`, and also `PdfLatex + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf`, both generate the same error.

Questions:

- What should the build command be when using natbib? Don't assume I know anything.
- Any idea why this error occurs even when I don't reference biblatex as far as I know?

Comment: Delete you `.bbl` file

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed it! Please post that as the answer certainly. And thank you!

Comment: You need `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because clearing the auxiliary files solved the problem.

Comment: @JosephWright This worked for me. Thanks